# Export Eclipse Project with native library

Tags: eclipse, jar, native, runnable

I would like export my eclipse project to create a runnable jar file. The problem is, that i am using a native library (*.so file).

How can I export my project with this library? Furthmore, the jar file should be executable in windows and linux.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think that's possible. Cross-platform runnable JAR file (double-click to start) is easy, even with including all referenced libraries i.e. other JARs (see [One-JAR](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/)).

However, how do you expect the Unix native lib to be available on Windows? One would need to decompile it first and then cross-compile for Windows. It's a different story of course if you have a DDL for Windows that is equal to the *.so for Unix. Then you simply package both into the JAR with One-JAR.

Comment: Ok, then I gonna try to get the DDL file for my native files aswell.